# Re-ordering Sequence in Scala

Tags: scala, sorting, sequence

Suppose I have a `Seq[Int]`. Now I would like to re-order the sequence to put the sequence elements <= 0 first and elements > 0 after them. How to do it simply and efficiently in `Scala` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest:

```
xs.sortBy(_ > 0)
```

Slightly more efficient:

```
xs.groupBy(_ > 0).toSeq.sortBy(_._1).flatMap(_._2)
```

More efficient yet:

```
xs.partition(_ <= 0) match { case(a,b) => a ++ b }
```

More efficient yet is to work directly with arrays.  Since you start with `Seq[Int]`, I'm assuming you aren't that pressed for speed.

Answer (score 2):

Its simple and pretty fast:

```
Seq(1, -1, 4, 2, -3, 6, -4).partition(_ <= 0) match{
    case (smaller, bigger) => smaller ++ bigger
}
//List(-1, -3, -4, 1, 4, 2, 6)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
val (xs, ys) = Seq(-1, 1, -2, 2, 3, -3, 0).partition(_ <= 0)
val zs = xs ++ ys
  // List(-1, -2, -3, 0, 1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
def reorder(xs: Seq[Int]): Seq[Int] =
  ((_: Seq[Int]) ++ (_: Seq[Int])) tupled xs.partition(_ <= 0)
```